# Алгоритм на поиск количество слагаемых в С

Tags: c, алгоритм

Уже несколько дней думаю как максимально эффективно это сделать, но пока в голове банальный перебор

Имею на входе

```
Числа вроде: 1 2 5 10 50 100

Потом суммы: 3 8 4 30
```

Хочу найти посчитать минимальное кол-во слагаемых из "**Числа вроде**" для поиска каждого числа из "**Потом суммы**"

то есть:
на выходе должно быть соответсвенно четыре числа (ответ взято в [ ])

```
[ 2 ]   - потому что (1+2=3)
[ 3 ]   -            (1+2+5=8)
[ 2 ]   -            (2+2=4)
[ 3 ]   -            (10+10+10=30)
```

1. Суммы не могут быть отрицательными
2. диапазон - int(от 0 включительно) int max
3. чисел может быть больше чем сумм
4. суммы может и не быть - программа напишет что решения нет и перейдет к след числу.

Comment: а ответ на С++ подойдёт или нужно точно на С?

Comment: вообще лучше на си, но если так, то в идеале тогда уже кодом, что бы мог "пересобрать"

Comment: можете сюда глянуть тогда https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-count-of-numbers-required-from-given-array-to-represent-s/

Comment: Условие не чёткое. Задача комбинаторная. Нужно вывести все перестановки, или часть перестановок? Если не все перестановки, а только с определённым условием - то задача проще. Если все перестановки - задача на графы, либо решается комбинаторыми приколами.

Comment: Числа\суммы могут быть нулем или отрицательными? У чисел\сумм есть какой то диапазон значений? Есть ли гарантия, что хотя бы одна сумма найдется? Сами то что пытались сделать?

Comment: @tym32167добвил в описание

Comment: @nick_n_a к сожалению четче уже некуда

Comment: @GGO спасибо, это именно то, что искал, жако что на си++, буду думать как перевести разумно ибо не вижу в гугле эквивалента :(

Comment: @tym32167 отпишите пожалуйста, если будут идеи

Comment: "Числа вроде" подозрительно похожи на номиналы денег. Если это так, то решается жадным алгоритмом, если ряд чисел произвольный - то динамическим программированием.

Comment: @MBo это могли бы быть денги, но нет, это числа)

Comment: @MBo я вот только в душе не люблю как жадный тут применить, в си++ наглядно понятно, но с си не очень

Comment: Что за детский сад...

Comment: Это задача о количестве способов размена. Да - монетки. :)

Comment: @MBo ну извините, что вы уже не в детском, я только изучаю программирование. И в си я не нашел примера применения

Comment: C тут ни причем. Вы алгоритм решения понимаете? На пальцах объяснить можете?

Comment: Задача о размене суммы - найти количество способов размена произвольными монетками. Алгоритм можно описать словами. Поможет?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy естесственно, только вот сложно математику превратить в код когда, ты только изучаешь как и что работает. я вообще не понимаю к чему эти странные вопросы

Comment: @MBo спасибо, помогло, хотя бы представление есть как это выглядит и можно сидеть разбиратьс, потому что раньше я вообще не мог подобное найти

Comment: @deniskalistrat, если ответ помог поставьте зеленую галочку на ответе.

Answer (score 3):

Заводим массив целых `A[]` длиной `Sum+1` для хранения минимальных количеств слагаемых для каждой суммы, инициализируем большим числом, нулевая ячейка = 0

Обходим массив номиналов. Для каждого номинала `V` проходим по ячейкам `A`.

Если `A[i + V]` больше, чем `A[i]+1`, то записываем в `A[i + V]` значение `A[i]+1` - это означает, что сумму `i+V` выгоднее составить с использованием монеты `V`.

В конце `А[Sum]` содержит минимальное количество монет

```
data = [2,3,5,7,11,13]
summ = 17
a = [9999]*(summ+1)
a[0] = 0
for v in data:
    for i in range(0, summ + 1 - v):
        if a[i+v] > a[i] + 1:
            a[i+v] = a[i] + 1
print(a[summ])
```

Comment: тоопчик, спасибо!

Comment: класическое использование ДП + еще и оптимальное решение

Comment: Ничего не понял, можно добавить код на любом языке. Спасибо.

Comment: @Leonid Да всё же по шагам расписано. Вот буквальная реализация.

Comment: Непонятно было, что значит "большим числом"  (бОльшим или большИм) и насколько большим???))) Теперь разобрался, спасибо.

Comment: @Leonid Можно для заполнения использовать число `summ/min(data)+1`

Answer (score 1):

### Теория

Через `t(j), 1 <= j <= n` обозначим слагаемые которые составляют сумму.
Пусть мы составили сумму `s` минимальным набором слагаемых из `t(j)`. Уберем из набора одно слагаемое. Получится сумма `s - t(j)`. Новый набор слагаемых для неё тоже минимальный, иначе возьмём набор меньшего размера, добавим к нему одно слагаемое, получим набор для `s` меньше того с которого начинали. Противоречие.

Обозначим через `c(s)` минимальное количество слагаемых нужное чтобы составить сумму `s`. Тогда верны такие соотношения:

```
c(s) = с(s - t(j)) + 1, если t(j) входит в минимальный набор
c(s) < с(s - t(j)) + 1, если t(j) не входит в минимальный набор
```

Чтобы вычислить `c(s)` надо попробовать удалять слагаемые по одному и брать минимальный результат:

```
c(s) = 1 + min(с(s - t(j)), 1 <= j <= n)
```

Формула выше не совсем честная: `c(s)` не определена если `s < 0` и если сумму вообще нельзя составить. В обоих случах положим что `c(s) = +inf`. Формула станет верной всегда.

Последний штрих: `c(0) = 0` - нулевую сумму составляем пустым набором
слагаемых.

### Практика

Бесконечность в программе на `C` будут представлять беззнаковые числа большие `INT_MAX`. Значение `c(s)` считаем последовательно от единицы до требуемой суммы. Значения хранятся с массиве `cs`. Последнее число из массива - ответ:

```
unsigned c(unsigned n, unsigned ts[/* n */], unsigned s) {
    unsigned *cs = malloc(sizeof(unsigned) * (s + 1));
    if (cs == NULL) {
       exit(1);
    }
    cs[0] = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= s; ++i) {
        unsigned min_c = 1u + (unsigned)INT_MAX;
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            unsigned t = ts[j];
            if (0 < t && t <= i) {
                unsigned c = cs[i - t];
                if (c < min_c) {
                    min_c = c;
                }
            }
        }
        cs[i] = min_c + 1;
    }
    unsigned c = cs[s];
    free(cs);
    return c;
}
```

Формат ввода не самый удобный для `C`: сложная функция `read_list` читает числа из одной строки в массив.

В функции `c` не используется
[VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array#C99) - большой массив таким образом не выделить, а нужен массив размером до `4 * 2^31 + 1` (8GB).

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    unsigned size;
    unsigned capacity;
    unsigned *data;
} list_t;

void append(list_t *list, unsigned v) {
    if (list->capacity == list->size) {
        unsigned capacity = 2 * list->capacity + 1;
        unsigned *data = realloc(list->data, sizeof(unsigned) * capacity);
        if (data == 0) {
            exit(1);
        }
        list->capacity = capacity;
        list->data = data;
    }
    list->data[list->size++] = v;
}

bool skip_spaces() {
    for (; ; ) {
        int c = getc(stdin);
        if (c == EOF) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!isspace(c)) {
            ungetc(c, stdin);
            return true;
        }
        if (c == '\n' || c == '\r') {
            ungetc(c, stdin);
            return false;
        }
    }
}

void read_list(list_t *list) {
    do {
        unsigned n;
        if (scanf("%u", &n) != 1 || n > INT_MAX) {
            exit(1);
        }
        append(list, n);
    } while (skip_spaces());
}

unsigned c(unsigned n, unsigned ts[/* n */], unsigned s) {
    unsigned *cs = malloc(sizeof(unsigned) * (s + 1));
    if (cs == NULL) {
       exit(1);
    }
    cs[0] = 0;
    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= s; ++i) {
        unsigned min_c = 1u + (unsigned)INT_MAX;
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            unsigned t = ts[j];
            if (0 < t && t <= i) {
                unsigned c = cs[i - t];
                if (c < min_c) {
                    min_c = c;
                }
            }
        }
        cs[i] = min_c + 1;
    }
    unsigned c = cs[s];
    free(cs);
    return c;
}

int main() {
    list_t terms = {0};
    read_list(&terms);
    printf("terms");
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < terms.size; ++i) {
        printf(" %u", terms.data[i]);
    }
    puts("\n");

    unsigned s;
    while (scanf("%u", &s) == 1 && s <= INT_MAX) {
        printf("sum %u -> ", s);
        unsigned c_ = c(terms.size, terms.data, s);
        if (c_ <= INT_MAX) {
            printf("%u", c_);
        } else {
            putc('?', stdout);
        }
        puts("");
    }
}
```

> ```
> $ gcc -std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -O3 shortest-sum.c
>
> $ cat in1
> 1 2 5 10 50 100
> 3 8 4 30
>
> $ ./a.out < in1
> terms 1 2 5 10 50 100
>
> sum 3 -> 2
> sum 8 -> 3
> sum 4 -> 2
> sum 30 -> 3
>
> $ cat in7
> 1 10 100 1000 10000 100000 1000000 10000000 100000000 1000000000
> 2147483647
>
> $ time ./a.out < in7
> terms 1 10 100 1000 10000 100000 1000000 10000000 100000000 1000000000
>
> sum 2147483647 -> 46
>
> real  0m33.661s
> user  0m31.316s
> sys   0m2.176s
> ```