# Есть мост длина n и доски [1,2,3,8]. Построить мост наименьшим количеством использование досок

Tags: javascript

JS.Есть мост длина n, например 68м и доски чтобы построить мост. Длина досок разные и не знаем сколько их,например 1,2,3,8(м). Досок от каждого размера бесконечно , но нужно найти вариант чтобы построить мост наименьшим количеством использование досок.

```
function solve(arr, n) {
  let res = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
      for (let k = 0; k < arr.length; k++) {
        res.push(arr[i] + arr[j] + arr[k]);
      }
    }
  }
res.forEach(e => { if(e == n) return e })
}
solve([1,2,3,8], 68);
```

код работает не так

Comment: Сколько досок самой большой длины поместится в мост длины n? Какой получится остаток? сколько досок второй длины поместится в остаток и так далее...

Comment: понимаю , но не могу реализовать и думаю что столько вложенных циклов это нехорошо

Comment: При чём тут вложенные циклы? достаточно тупого деления с остатком. А в общем случае это задача линейного раскроя с дополнительным ограничением... полненькая такая.

Comment: @VardanHakobyan, Akina развернул мою мысль. )) Делите n на самое большое значение из массива, получаете частное от деления (сколько досок такой длины можно уложить в мост длиной n) и остаток, сколько осталось метров. Если остаток не ноль - делите его на второй по размеру элемент массива и так далее, пока остаток не будет равен нулю. ))

Comment: уважаемые, алгоритм понимаю , но реализовать не могу)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Жадный алгоритм (брать доски максимальной длины, сколько возможно, потом следующие) будет работать **не для всех наборов данных**. Например, для `[1,6,10]` и длины `12` жадный алгоритм даст `3`, а правильно - `2`.

А полноценно решить задачу можно с помощью динамического программирования - это задача о наборе суммы минимальным количеством монет.

Заведите массив `A` длиной `n+1`, заполните большим числом, кроме нулевой ячейки и для каждой длины доски `L` проверяйте ячейки, и обновляйте те, для которых `A[i-L]+1` меньше текущего значения `A[i]`

Comment: Кстати, да, не подумал.

Comment: это правильно, но у меня нет навыка это в код превратить)

Comment: @Vardan Hakobyan Описание какой части не получается реализовать? Циклы for и сравнения if ведь Вам известны.  [вот описание чуть другими словами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1215968/291659)

Comment: @MBo я понимаю мысль которое решает задачу , но то что к чему в коде будет не могу преобразовывать

Answer (score 0):

Накатал такой вариант:

```js
function Boards(arr, metr) {
    arr = arr.sort(function (a,b){return (a + b)}); // Сортируем массив с длиной досок по убыванию
    let width = metr, res = []; // Переменные для хранения данных
  
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { // Проходим по массиву размеров досок
    if(width > 0) { // Если общая длина моста ещё не закончилась, то:
        let col = Math.floor(width / arr[i]); // Получаем количество досок, получая целое число от деления общей длины моста на длину доски.
        if(col > 0) { // Если длина больше нуля, то:
                res.push({ // Добавляем в массив, в котором будем хранить:
            col: col, // количество досок
          width: arr[i], // длина доски
          fullwidth: (arr[i] * col) // общая длина
        });
            width = width - res[res.length-1].fullwidth; // Каждый раз вычетаем общую длину досок из длины моста.
      } else continue; // Если количество меньше или равно нулю, то пропускаем эти доски и идём к следующим
    } else break; // Если длина моста закончилась, то прерываем цикл.
  }
  
  // Выводим результат
  console.info('Чтобы выложить мост длиной '+metr+'м нужно:');
  for(let i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
    console.info('- '+res[i].col+' '+declOfNum(res[i].col, ['доска', 'доски', 'досок'])+', длиной '+res[i].width+'м, общая длина = '+res[i].fullwidth+'м');
  }
} Boards([1,2,3,8], 68);

// Для красоты
function declOfNum(number,titles){ 
  cases = [2,0,1,1,1,2]; 
  return titles[(number%100>4 && number%100<20)? 2 : cases[(number%10<5)?number%10:5]]; 
}
```

Comment: нужно найти вариант который использует минимальное количество досок , для [1,2,3,8], 68 ответ 10 , 8x8 , 1x3 , 1x1

Comment: Создайте вначале функции переменную, допустим `let full = 0;` и каждый проход добавляйте количество досок, в моём случае `full += res[res.length-1].col`, тогда получите количество досок всего.